# How to do a Lucene.Net search for local results based on geographic location?

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I'm looking for some info so that users can find local results in their Lucene.Net searches.

I would index the latitude/longitude of the location in the document, and query Lucene based on the users position and 20 (or 30, 40...) mile range.

Answer (score 3):

The utmost on local search in Lucene is Grant Ingersoll's [Location-aware search with Apache Lucene and Solr](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/j-spatial/index.html?ca=drs-&utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter). Trouble is that Lucene.net lags after Java Lucene, so that these Lucene features available with the rather new Lucene 2.9.0 will take a while to trickle into Lucene.net (Lucene.net 2.4.0 came about a year after Java Lucene's 2.4.0). In the meantime, 
try [Spatial.net](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/lucene.net/trunk/C%23/contrib/Spatial.Net/Spatial.Net/Overview.html) in Lucene.net's contrib, or you can try to port [Sujit Pal's suggestions](http://sujitpal.blogspot.com/2008/02/spatial-search-with-lucene.html) from Java to C#.